# How can I use class property use extension method

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium class

```
 public class Driver
    {
        public IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
        public  string baseURL;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://localhost:49730/";
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }

        public void Wait(TimeSpan timespan)
        {
            Thread.Sleep((int)(timespan.TotalSeconds * 1000));
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            Instance.Close();;
        }
    }
```

I have also created an extension method which is an Explicit Wait

```
public static class WebDriverExtensionMethods

    public static class WebDriverExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(this Driver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
                return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
            }
            return driver.Instance.FindElement(by);
        }
    }
```

How can I call the method with the Driver class property? I.e. I want to call driver.Instance.WaitAndFindElement

Comment: It looks like your extension method should be on `IWebDriver` - *or* call it with just `driver.WaitAndFindElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can write an extension on IWebDriver, instead of Driver:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensionMethods
{
    public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
}
```

Btw, this way you could only call it on driver's Instance property. Otherwise you could add this extension in addition to the one you already have. Maybe even extracting common code:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensionMethods
{
    private static IWebElement WaitAndFindElementInternal(IWebDriver webDriver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return webDriver.FindElement(by);
    }

    public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(this Driver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        return WaitAndFindElementInternal(driver.Instance, by, timeoutInSeconds);
    }

    public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        return WaitAndFindElementInternal(driver, by, timeoutInSeconds);
    }
}
```

This way you can call `driver.Instance.WaitAndFindElement` as well as `driver.WaitAndFindElement`.

Comment: thanks for helping to see the flaw in my paramters. Also thanks for that extra effort on those extension methods